# Custom validation error message in django rest framework ImageField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm trying to create my custom validation error messages in django rest framework.

I have a productSerializer like the below code:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # validation

    name = serializers.CharField(error_messages={'blank': 'Please fillout the product name!'})

    price = serializers.FloatField(error_messages={'blank': 'Please fillout the product price!'})
    
    slug = serializers.SlugField(error_messages={'blank': 'Please fillout the product slug!'})

    size = serializers.CharField(error_messages={'blank': 'Please fillout the product size!'})

    description = serializers.CharField(error_messages={'blank': 'Please fillout the description!'})

    image = serializers.ImageField(error_messages={'blank': 'Please upload a photo image!'})

    # validation
    category = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=False)
    productType = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

and my views.py be like:

```
class ProductsList(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        category = Category.objects.get(name=request.data['category'])
        productType = ProductType.objects.get(name=request.data['productType'])

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(category=category, productType=productType)
            return Response("SUCCESS!!!!!!", status=200)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

**The problem**:
I want the image field error message to be what I've written, when it's blank.
But I always face the message "No file was submitted."

**Question**:
How can I validate the image field being blank?

Comment: What is the current behavior when the image is blank?

Comment: @JPG It gives me the response of "{"image": ["No file was submitted."]}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
class Meta:
    model = Product
    extra_kwargs = {
        "image": {
            "error_messages": {
                "required": "Please upload a photo image"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but there were no positive results. The code that I have written is completely equal to your answer, but in a different way. I need to catch the error whenever the field is empty, that means "blank".

Answer (score 1):

You can add [object-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) to your serializer to raise ValidationError with a custom message.

You can modify your serializer in such a way:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# validation

name = serializers.CharField(error_messages={'blank': 'Please fillout the product name!'})

price = serializers.FloatField(error_messages={'blank': 'Please fillout the product price!'})

slug = serializers.SlugField(error_messages={'blank': 'Please fillout the product slug!'})

size = serializers.CharField(error_messages={'blank': 'Please fillout the product size!'})

description = serializers.CharField(error_messages={'blank': 'Please fillout the description!'})

image = serializers.ImageField(required=False, error_messages={'blank': 'Please upload a photo image!'})

# validation
category = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=False)
productType = serializers.StringRelatedField()
user = serializers.StringRelatedField()

def validate(self, data):
    if "image" not in data:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Please upload a photo image!")
    return data


class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = "__all__"
```

EDIT: You probably also need to set required=False for your ImageField so that the serializer will not raise that the field is missing (because required is True by default in all serializers.Field) before your .validate() method.

You can also test [field-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) but I am afraid that the the fact that this field is missing will be raised before your custom field-level validation method will be called.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately that didn't help me. I need to validate the blank image field. Image field, blank or filled, is always sent from the client to the server,  so there are no required error in the application.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by 'blank image'? Is it null or maybe it is when client hasn't sent this field at all? I see that ImageField has 'allow_empty_file' parameter, which is by default False. Maybe you can change it to True so the serializer will pass the data to your custom .validate() method for further validation instead of raising "No file was submitted." Then in the .validate() you can check if 'image' is in data and if 'image' is not None.

Comment: Well I mean the case when the image field is being sent from the client side, but the user has not put any image in it so the field is blank. I also tried `allow_empty_file = True` on the serializer but there were no changes. `required = False` does not change anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, add this `def validate_` method in your serializer class -

```
def validate_image(self, image):

    image = image.strip()

    # this will check if the image is blank. If it is then it will raise a 
    # validation error.

    if not image:

        raise serializers.ValidationError("Please upload a photo image!")

    return image
```

Comment: How can I modify this error representation from ```{"email": ["This field is required."]}``` to ```{"email": "This field is required."}```